# S3 creating empty files when uploading a file from React contact form using Axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, amazon-s3, axios

I have created a test contact form where a user can upload an image attachment.

- The presignedURL AWS Lambda function works fine
- The image file (blob) is showing up as an image in the html, so it's added correctly
- When image is posted, I get a successful 200 response and the file appears in S3

However, **in S3 all files appear empty**. The size seems to change depending on the length of the link size (e.g. blob is 63B, a hard-coded link varies in size), so it seems like it just takes the link as data, not the actual image. I checked many times if my axios syntax is correct and went through numerous threads here in SO but can't figure out what am I doing wrong.

AWS Lambda to generate the presigned URL:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
AWS.config.update({ region: 'eu-west-2' })
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

const uploadBucket = 'xxx-bucket'

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  const result = await getUploadURL()
  console.log('Result: ', result)
  return result
};

const getUploadURL = async function() {
  console.log('getUploadURL started')
  let actionId = Date.now()

  var s3Params = {
    Bucket: uploadBucket,
    Key:  `${actionId}.jpg`,
    ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
    CacheControl: 'max-age=31104000',
    ACL: 'public-read'
  };

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Get signed URL
    let uploadURL = s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', s3Params)
    resolve({
      "statusCode": 200,
      "isBase64Encoded": false,
      "headers": {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
      },
      "body": JSON.stringify({
          "uploadURL": uploadURL,
          "photoFilename": `${actionId}.jpg`
      })
    })
  })
}
```

React Frontend:

```
class QuoteForm extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      file:null,
    };
  };

  onContactNameChange(e){
    this.setState({ContactName:e.target.value});
  };

  onFileChange(e){
    let [file] = e.target.files;
    if (file) {
      this.setState({
        file: URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]),
      });
      console.log(file);
    }
  };

  async handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  
      axios.post(`https://xxxx/`)
      .then(res => {
            console.log(res)
            const url = res.data.uploadURL;

            const axiosConfig = {
                headers: { 
                    "Content-Type": "image/jpeg",
                    "Cache-Control": 'max-age=31104000' 
                }
            }

            axios.put(url, this.state.file, axiosConfig)
                .then(response => {console.log(response)}).catch(err => {console.log(err.response)
            });
        });

    }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
            <input 
                type="file"
                name="file"
                id="fileUpload" 
                onChange={this.onFileChange.bind(this)}
            />

            <img src={this.state.file} alt="img" />

            <button 
                className="large"
                style={{marginTop:"1.25rem"}} >
                Submit
            </button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

S3 Bucket files:
[image]

I just can't understand why the files in S3 bucket turn up empty.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured out what was my issue. `createObjectURL` in my frontend React code apparently can't be used to upload files to server since it doesn't actually include the file, but the URL only. I shortened the whole `onFileChange(e)` function to the one below and S3 started receiving the actual files.

```
  onFileChange(e){
        const [selectedFile] = e.target.files;
    if (selectedFile) {
            this.setState({file:selectedFile})
        }
  };
```